# SQL command not properly ended - problem with joining?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to read data and calculate the count of LASNRO and sum of LASKMKEALV for each LYTUNNUS, but I get the error message of:

ORA-00933: SQL-komento ei päättynyt oikein 00933.
00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 20

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer, if it matters.

```
SELECT
    TUNNUS,
    LYTUNNUS,
    COUNT(LASNRO), 
    SUM(LASKMKEALV)
FROM
    XX.XX AS T1
        INNER JOIN
    YY.YY AS T2 ON T1.TUNNUS = T2.ASTUNNUS
GROUP BY
    LYTUNNUS
ORDER BY
    COUNT(LASKMKEALV) DESC;
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. (I.e. try `GROUP BY TUNNUS, LYTUNNUS`.)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not allow `as` for table aliases.  So the `FROM` clause should be:

```
FROM XX.XX T1 JOIN
     YY.YY T2
     ON T1.TUNNUS = T2.ASTUNNUS
```

The query you seem to want is:

```
SELECT TUNNUS,
       COUNT(LASNRO), 
       SUM(LASKMKEALV)
FROM XX.XX T1 INNER JOIN
     YY.YY T2
     ON T1.TUNNUS = T2.ASTUNNUS
GROUP BY LYTUNNUS
ORDER BY COUNT(LASKMKEALV) DESC;
```

Comment: how did you become a genius in oracle. I am looking for some tips thanks.

Comment: This was new to me as I have previously used only MySql. Now I received a different error:  ORA-00979: tämä ei ole GROUP BY -lauseke
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 2

Comment: @Kimmo . . . Your `SELECT` columns are not consistent with the `GROUP BY` columns.  Remove the second column.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
with_order_col AS (
  SELECT
      tunnus,
      lytunnus,
      COUNT(lasnro)     AS lasnro_count, 
      SUM(laskmkealv)   AS laskmkealv_sum,
      COUNT(laskmkealv) AS laskmkealv_count
  FROM xx.xx t1
  JOIN yy.yy t2 ON t1.tunnus = t2.astunnus
  GROUP BY
    tunnus, -- you must GROUP BY every column that is not an aggregate function
    lytunnus
)
SELECT
  tunnus,
  lytunnus,
  lasnro_count,
  laskmkealv_sum
FROM with_order_col  
ORDER BY
  laskmkealv_count DESC
;
```